# How to prevent immediate wake ups when using Wake On Phy / Unicast?

Tags: linux, wake-on-lan, lubuntu

Right now I can use wake on lan with magic packets but I'd like to be able to wake my machine by network activity, so I don't have to use a tool to send magic packets. It should wake if I'd like to access it eg. via samba share.

As far as I know wol p (phy) or u (unicast) options should do the trick (according to [ethtool man](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#Enable_WoL_on_the_network_adapter)). But when I turn on either of these options my machine wakes up immediately from sleep (S3) or shutdown (S5).

Please note that if I turn on **just** the g (magic packet activity) option it stops waking automatically (and successfully wakes when I send magic packet to it).

- OS: Lubuntu 17.10
- My machine is an
  Intel D525MW

I'm guessing it wakes up automatically because it is connected to the router. But if it's true, how am I suppose to use "Wake on phy activity" or "Wake on unicast messages" then? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I still find this unclear.  (1) Are you saying that, if you enable ``p`` or ``u`` mode Wake-on-LAN, then you *cannot shutdown* your machine, or put it to sleep, because it comes right back up after you shut it down?  After reading your question for the fourth time, I got the idea that that was maybe your problem — and I see that you came close to saying that (“if I turn on **just** the g (magic packet activity) option I can put the machine to sleep or shut it down properly”), but then edited it out.  (2) I guess I’m just dumb.  What are S3 and S5? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  P.S.  Do you have another machine (computer) on the same LAN? (Can you borrow one?) Can you sniff the network (e.g., with a tool like Wireshark) during the critical moment and get a clearer idea of what is happening?

Comment: (1) Yes, exactly. (I edited a lot of times to be suited for you ;) ) (2) S3 and S5 are power modes as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And yes, I have another machine in the network so I can "sniff" around; thank you for the advice. Only used Wireshark once, and only for inspecting traffic on the same machine as Wireshark was running on, so I don't know yet how to inspect all the traffic running through my router but I will look after it. Will report back the results. Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?